# Netsuite - How do you export/search Vendor List with ALL addresses?

Tags: list, csv, export, netsuite, vendor

I am trying to pull all vendors with all associated addresses. (Some vendors have more than 10 addresses). How would I do this through a search to see all addresses and not only one or two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a vendor search with no filters and set the columns to the address fields like this:

[image: Like this]

The results should show one row per address.